# Proving full rank of a special type of a (0,1,2)-integer matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, integers, matrix-rank, polytopes, hypergraphs

My question arise at the consideration of Newton polytopes. In that context

> I consider integer matrices  $ A =(a_{ij})\in \mathbb{Z}^{(n+1) \times N} $ with $n+1 \leq N$ having the following special properties
>
> - $a_{ij}\in \{0;1;2\}$
> - first row is fixed: $a_{1j} = 1$ for all $j$
> - the column-sums have only two possible values $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{ij} \in \{K;K+1\}$ with $2\leq K \leq n+1$
> - columns which satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{ij} = K$ can only contain $a_{ij}\in\{0;1\}$
> - all columns are distinct: for $j\neq j^\prime$ there is an $i$ with $a_{ij} \neq a_{ij^\prime}$
>
> and I want to check if/prove that those matrices have the full rank: 
>   $\operatorname{rank} (A) = n+1$.

Also a proof for the special case $a_{ij}\in\{0;1\}$ would help me.

The following equivalent statements I have found:

- the column vectors without the first entry are affinely independent
- the convex hull of $A$ without the first row has the full dimension $n$

And I tried (currently without success) to interprete $A$ as an incidence matrix of a hypergraph with $K$- and $(K+1)$-regular part.

Thanks a lot

Comment: "all columns are different" I think you intended: when $j \neq j' \; ,$ there is at least one $i$ with $a_{ij} \neq a_{ij'}$

Comment: @WillJagy: Thanks for your comment. Of course I mean the whole columns are distinct. My notation was a little bit messy,

Comment: Is $K$ a given number?

Comment: @Reen I suggest finding all such matrices that are square, for $N$ as large as you can manage. The other part: we require that all the columns with sum $K$ occur on the left, and all the columns with sum $K+1$ occur on the right. I do not (yet) say this will show how to finish the problem but it might. It seems possible from experiments by hand that the determinant is odd; therefore nonzero. Of course, I admit to somewhat losing track of cases in 4 by 4. Easy enough for a computer, your rules are pretty restrictive.

Comment: @user1551, no, I wouldn't think $K$ given ahead of time. I think the square such matrices have odd determinant. I guess I have up to 4 by 4 worked out, nice to find out what happens in 5 by 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1&0\\
1&0&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&0&1\\
1&1&1&0&0}\pmatrix{1\\ 0\\ -1\\ 1\\ -1}=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the discussion and for that counterexample. I've also tried only up to 4x4. 
Thus, I think I have to adjust my polytopes, such that they are restrictive enough to provide full rank matrices.